# Is this a design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, .net

I have following C# code. It helped me to avoid some code repetition in a good way.

The `ExecuteQueryGenericApproach<T>` method receives a `Func` generic delegate as argument. The delegated method has a parameter which receives `IDataRecord` as argument.  That is, the  `ExecuteQueryGenericApproach<T>` method provides the required IDataRecord to the functions passed to it.

**QUESTIONS**

1. What is the name of this pattern? (Based on `GoF` design patterns)
2. Is there any other scenario where this pattern is used?

**Note**: Knowing the name of this pattern will help me to better research on this and find opportunities to use it.

CommonDAL

```
public class CommonDAL
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQueryGenericApproach<T>(string commandText, List<SqlParameter> commandParameters, Func<IDataRecord, T> methodToExecute)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Server=XXXX;Database=AS400_Source;User Id=dxxx;Password=xxxx5";

        //Action, Func and Predicate are pre-defined Generic delegates.
        //So as delegate they can point to functions with specified signature.

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = commandText;
                command.CommandTimeout = 0;

                if (commandParameters != null)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddRange(commandParameters.ToArray());
                }

                connection.Open();
                using (var rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        yield return methodToExecute(rdr);
                    }
                    rdr.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EmployeeDAL

```
 public class EmployeeRepositoryDAL
    {
        public static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            string commandText = @"SELECT E.EmployeeID,E.EmployeeName,R.RoleID,R.RoleName FROM dbo.EmployeeRole ER
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.Employee E  ON E.EmployeeID= ER.EmployeeID
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.[Role] R ON R.RoleID= Er.RoleID ";

            //IEnumerable<Employee> employees = MyCommonDAL.ExecuteQueryGenericApproach<Employee>(commandText, commandParameters, Employee.EmployeeFactory);

            //Group By is needed for listing all the roles for an employee.
            IEnumerable<Employee> employees = CommonDAL.ExecuteQueryGenericApproach<Employee>(commandText, null, Employee.EmployeeCreator)
                                                    .GroupBy(x => new { x.EmployeeID, x.EmployeeName },
                                                            (key, group) =>
                                                                            new Employee
                                                                            {
                                                                                EmployeeID = key.EmployeeID,
                                                                                EmployeeName = key.EmployeeName,
                                                                                Roles = group.SelectMany(v => v.Roles).ToList()
                                                                            }
                                                            ).ToList();


            return employees.ToList();
        }


    }
```

Entity

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    //IDataRecord Provides access to the column values within each row for a DataReader
    //IDataRecord is implemented by .NET Framework data providers that access relational databases.

    //Static Method
    public static Employee EmployeeCreator(IDataRecord record)
    {
        var employee = new Employee
        {
            EmployeeID = (int)record[0],
            EmployeeName = (string)record[1],
            Roles = new List<Role>()
        };

        employee.Roles.Add(new Role { RoleID = (int)record[2], RoleName = (string)record[3] });
        return employee;

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe remove some of the implementation details so that your pattern becomes more obvious? I don't think that the problem domain (Employee modelling), SQL requests, or details of the implementation language are really relevant to demonstrate this pattern.

Comment: @amon I have provided a high level summary on the top portion of the post. I think it is good to have the complete code and it is not too lengthy.

Comment: The high level overview makes it sound like a higher-order functional implementation of the strategy pattern. You'll not find that specific case in many OO design pattern books because the object oriented types are only just realising that functional programming has a lot to teach them.

Comment: I wouldn't say you've found a pattern, but you've created the bare workings of an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think this is a design pattern. First reason is that GoF design patterns were are OOP with zero knowledge of first-class functions or generics. Both which are used in your example.

One important thing to remember: Not everything is a design pattern. Just because something saved you some time doesn't make it a design pattern. If you follow a proper design principles, you can create a good, extensible code without even knowing a single design pattern. Design patterns are only good if you want to communicate what the code does to someone else.

Comment: The word "communicate" is the key point. If we can figure out what is the name I can easily communicate with other team members. Generics and Delegates are easier ways of implementing design patterns in C#.

Comment: @Lijo If you want to name it, then do it. But make sure you have solid definition what falls under that name and what does not. And I disagree about generics and delegates. They actually make OOP design patterns much harder to understand.

Comment: Just because something wasn't in the GoF book doesn't mean it isn't a design pattern.  If you find that you're repeating a particular pattern when you design your code, guess what?  It's a design pattern.